# asp button postback inside div with (display:none)

Tags: html, dopostback, aspbutton

I have a html button that calls an asp button to dopostback, but nothing happens.

```
<input type='button' value='click me' id='btntoClick'/>

<div id='divServerBtn' style='display:none'>
<asp:button ID='myButton' runat='server' onClick='myOnclickMethod'> </div>
```

my jquery:

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#btntoClick").on("click", function(){ $("#myButton").click(); })
});
```

OR

if I set the div to visible at run time, still clicking the button does nothing, it goes to codebehind but **IsPostBack** is **false**

```
$(function(){       
  $("#divServerBtn").attr("display", "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this as a test, then modify your code accordingly.  The main thing is to use OnClientClick, not OnClick.  It is also important to include "return false;"

Your function:

```
    <script>
    function ShowMe() {
        $(function() {        
            $("#divServerBtn").show();
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Your aspx button and div example:

```
    <div id='divServerBtn' style='display:none'>Me</div>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowMe(); return false;" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

Comment: .toggle instead of .show will show/hide with every button click.  FYI.